# Error in getting token from GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

MainActivity.java -

```
package cc.campusconnect.devapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button btnRegId;
    EditText etRegId;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String regid;
    String PROJECT_NUMBER;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GCMButton);
        System.out.println("Here!");
        etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GCMId);
        PROJECT_NUMBER = "507533032900";
        btnRegId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("I am here");
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),RegistrationIntentService.class);
                startService(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The other files included are here - [GCM Implementation Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart)

My Android Manifest file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="cc.campusconnect.devapp" >

     <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
             android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
         <receiver
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
             android:exported="true"
             android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <category android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp" />
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

         <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
         <service
             android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp.MyGcmListenerService"
             android:exported="false" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             </intent-filter>
         </service>
         <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
         <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
         <service
             android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
             android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>
         <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
         <service
             android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp.RegistrationIntentService"
             android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <category android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp" />
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
                 <category android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp" />
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                 <category android:name="cc.campusconnect.devapp" />
             </intent-filter>
         </service>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

I have the configuration file generated and stored - as in the [Tutorial by Google](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

I get an error saying

```
 Failed to complete token refresh
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

What is the error? And how Do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You resolve this by adding the following permission in your manifest file:

```
 <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
```

Comment: Same error persists. I use an Virtual Device. Could that be there reason of some error? 

also - I haven't declared the R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (used in RegistrationIntentService.java) in strings.xml. If i do, i get gradle error saying double declaration.

Comment: well if it says that it means you defined it already, find it and make sure the sender id value is correct

Comment: its the same as project id, corretc?

Comment: and somehow, R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId is correct